# Python: redo last JSON request till something changes

Tags: python, json, parsing, google-api, sleep

I have an interesting question: how to ask Python to keep repeting the last action until I see a different result?

**Schenario:** I'm trying to retrieve `JSON` from Google API. My code is like:

- if `['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS'` I pass to the next Latitude,Longitude to inspect
- if `['status'] == 'OK'` I retrieve data from that Latitude,Longitude
- if `['status'] == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'` wait 24 hours and then try again **that** Latitude,Longitude

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

for val in "catcatcatcatcat":
    if val == "c":
        print(val)
    time.sleep(1)
    if val == "a":
        print(val)
    time.sleep(1)
    elif val == "t":
        # retray this last action till "t" has become "c" or "a"
    time.sleep(86400)
```

Google API stops my script after I dry out my request limit and my script needs to pause for 24h.
That's why that `"t"` in the and will become a `"c"` or an `"a"` but I don't want to restart parsing `JSON` from the beginning as I'm checking all Latitude,Longitude per country.

I want:

```
Parse JSON
Pause 24h
reparse that last JSON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

for val in "catcatcatcatcat":
    if val == "c":
        print(val)
    time.sleep(1)
    if val == "a":
        print(val)
    time.sleep(1)
    elif val == "t":
        while val == "t":
            print('We will retry this')
    time.sleep(86400)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    data = get_data()
    status = data['status']
    if status != 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT':
        break
    sleep(...)
if status == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
    ...
elif status == 'OK':
    ...
```